# How to configure my server for socket

Tags: c#

on local machine this code working but when i use for other machine it does not work.

```
 socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 PEndPoint localendpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.102"), 6001);
            try
            {socket.Connect(localendpoint);}
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("unable");
                Main(args);
            }
            String sms = "i;want;send;data";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sms);
            socket.Send(data);
            Console.Read();
            socket.Close();    }
```

my server side:

```
 socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.102"),6001));
 socket.Listen(100);
 Socket acepted = socket.Accept();
```

Actual i want configure other machine i used this same code with difrent IP but do not find  . other machine IP is 192.168.0.102 how to configure that is located in other place ?

Comment: Your server can listen on 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: i want use other machine so i cant use this . my other machine IP is 192.168.0.102 .

Answer (score 0):

Just listen on the [IPAddress.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) IP, so the server will listen to requests to literally any address it's assigned. This will allow you to connect from any network.

If you only want to let programs running on the same computer to be able to connect, use `IPAddress.Loopback`, which will make your socket listen on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @user1551503 "not working" is not an error message. Update your question with actual code, exception and stack trace.

Comment: check and plz give me some more ideas i want complete my project,

Comment: @user1551503 I still don't see why that is "not working". Any exceptions when you run the code?

Comment: just unable to connect with server .. other side server application is running properly .

Comment: server application is ruining on my laptop which is connected with other router. and my Clint program is on my computer with other router then server. both are connected with different routers.

Comment: @user1551503 can you ping the other machine? And of course, if you catch an exception without really catching it (i.e. `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }` but instead just print "unable", all you will see is "unable" without knowing why you couldn't connect. Get the error message and someone can help.

Comment: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005):
Error((((  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond \ r \ ncorretamente after
  a period of time, or established connection failed \ r \ nbecause connected host did not respond 192.168.0.102:6001

Comment: @user1551503 can you ping? Telnet? Is there a firewall in the way? Please show some effort yourself, we can't debug your application for you.

Comment: i used telnet 192.168.0.102:6001 its show me error conect fail. and if i used netstat -na it show me some tcp and some udp port of listening now i am confuse what have to do which port i can use ?

Comment: @user1551503 _"I used telnet 192.168.0.102:6001 its show me error conect fail"_ - then disable the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Using IPAddress.Any may expose you to all kinds of security risks as you will be listening on all NIC cards on your machine, including the internet & intranet one. Instead, use IPAddress.Loopback for your primary LAN NIC card. Or instead, store the ip-address of your desired NIC card in a database or config file.

Comment: IPAddress.Loopback does not listen on any NIC, it listens on the virtual loopback adapter, i.e. `127.0.0.1`. If that is what OP wants to do (that is: never let anyone apart from `localhost` connect), then it's OK. Storing the IP in config is not a good suggestion, it may change with every reboot. There are various ways to request all assigned IPs from all NICs on the current machine.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Suppose in a situation where I have multiple NIC cards on my local machine (connecting to several networks), and I want to listen on a particular NIC of my choice, then config file could be the only option. What other way is there?

Comment: Simply saying you can store something in a config file is never an answer. Are you going to let your user type their own IP address? There are various API calls in `System.Net` that let you enumerate all adapters in a system and all addresses assigned to those adapters.